# Adding button digit from calculator to variable via concatenation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, calculator

Starting to write a simple calculator in VB.NET just to further my skills in the language. I'm trying to write a segment that inputs digits via button presses into a variable.  Basically, the input would enter as a string, concatenate with the current variable value as a string, and the result would be converted to a double. Using a msgbox to check the output.

My main class:

```
Public Class FormMain

    Public firstNum As Double = 1 '0 won't work for whatever reason, still figuring that out
    Public secondNum As Double
    Public opUsed As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Button_Press(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonOne.Click, ButtonTwo.Click, ButtonThree.Click,
        ButtonFour.Click, ButtonFive.Click, ButtonSix.Click, ButtonSeven.Click, ButtonEight.Click, ButtonNine.Click, ButtonZero.Click
        'Handles button presses for each of the digit buttons
        'If branching below sends appropriate digit to the InputDigit Sub
        If sender Is ButtonOne Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 1)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonTwo Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 2)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonThree Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 3)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonFour Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 4)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonFive Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 5)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonSix Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 6)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonSeven Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 7)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonEight Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 8)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonNine Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 9)
        ElseIf sender Is ButtonZero Then
            Methods.InputDigit(opUsed, firstNum, secondNum, 0)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

And for my "Methods" class:

```
Friend Class Methods

    Public Overloads Shared Sub InputDigit(ByRef opUsed As Boolean, ByVal firstNum As Double, ByVal secondNum As Double, ByVal x As Integer)
        'Inputs digit into firstNum, else secondNum
        If opUsed = False Then
            firstNum = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum.ToString + x.ToString)
        Else
            secondNum = Convert.ToDouble(firstNum.ToString + x.ToString)
        End If
        MsgBox(firstNum)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The output when I press a button is always whatever value I assign firstNum concatenated with the button value, and it never increments. So if firstNum is 1, and I press ButtonOne, the msgbox will always say "11".

Comment: Confused on what you are asking. In a calculator I expect hitting `1` twice to give me `11`. Are you saying you hit for example `1 + 1` and are getting `11`? Your `InputDigit` method seems very iffy if `opUsed` was `True`. In my scenario, I see you still getting `11` for `secondNum` and still displaying `firstNum` in the message box. I suggest adding a break point in it and stepping through the code.

Comment: it looks like you want to pass firstNum and secondNum ByRef if you expect the Methods class to be able to change then 'outside the scope' of the InputDigit method, see this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/byval-byref